# Which spring controller to use when wants to get a java serialized object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to ask that spring has many controllers, such as FormControllers e.t.c. But each have a separate purpose.

I am sending java serialized object from another application. Now , i want to receive this object using spring controller, but i don't know which particular controller will do the job. I have explored some controllers such as sessionController and others. But still confused.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Why not use Spring RMI Invocation?

Comment: Can't use it. Its not in the requirements.

Comment: You need to write a controller to handle your work.  Try searching this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ or "@Controller"

Comment: Strange requirements if they prescribe technology… It is very easy to do with a `HttpInvoker` just configuration and nothing to write yourself. Also if you really want to have a portable solution you shouldn't be using java serialization but use XML or JSON instead.